# memcpy not-POD objects leads to undefined behavior

Tags: c++, memcpy

In what situation ,an object of Class will guarantee to insert `invisible data` into an object ?

People usually said that it's not OK when using `memcpy` of copying objects instead of `copy-assignment`, sometimes the compiler will insert invisible data into the objects. so after `memcpy` ,the object memory layout maybe crashed.

If it contains virutal function,then it is not POD.
But contains virtual ,the function may not crash ,it is not defined.
Can someone give me any example that the memcpy is surely wrong.

Some people said that `shared_ptr` affect `memcpy`, I tried, but it doesn't crash

can someone write an test demo to prove it ?

Comment: memcpy non-POD is undefined behavior. That's an affirmative statement (and it's true). What is the question?

Comment: `memcpy`ing a `shared_ptr` will almost guarantee accessing freed memory, and possibly a double delete.  Just because a simple example doesn't crash doesn't mean that it works.

Comment: I'd argue not crashing is worse than crashing in this case. In a more complex system, you'll be acting on garbage data and it'll be a confusing headache.

Answer (score 3):

`shared_ptr` is a good example: copying the object representation will give you a second pointer to the same object, but without incrementing the usage count. Once you've broken the invariant that the usage count must equal the number of pointers, you leave yourself open to undefined behaviour such as dereferencing dangling pointers, and deleting the same object twice:

```
shared_ptr<int> good(new int(42));
shared_ptr<int> evil;

memcpy(&evil, &good, sizeof evil); // Breaking invariant
good.reset();                      // Deletes object

*evil = 666;                       // BOOM! accesses deleted object
evil.reset();                      // BOOM! deletes object a second time.
```

You also mention virtual functions. These could cause problems if you copy the base sub-object of a derived class; the resulting object will (probably) point to the virtual table for the wrong class:

```
struct Base {
    virtual int f() {return 0;}
};

struct Derived : Base {
    int x;
    virtual int f() {return x;}
};

Base * good = new Derived;
Base evil;

memcpy(*evil, good, sizeof evil); // Base object with Derived vtable (probably)

evil->f(); // BOOM! probably accesses nonexistent member `x`
```